# 3.19 Rudin FA, positive borel measure, integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

> **(Rudin's Functional Analysis 3.29 pg 81):** Suppose $Q$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $X$ is a Banach space, $f:Q \rightarrow X$ is continuos, and **$\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $Q$**. Then 
>   $$ \Big| \Big| \int_Q f \, d\mu \Big| \Big| \le \int _Q ||f|| \,d \mu . $$

I am concerned with the *existence of integral*.

We know that the integral $\int_Q \,f d\mu $ exists when $\mu$ is a *finite probability measure*. (3.27, p78)

I see this means if $\mu$ is a *finite positive measure*, the integral exists by linearity.

> How does this hold for *general* positive measures?

I am thinking we might need the fact that $\mu$ is somehow locally finite - but even that I do not know how to prove.

Comment: I don't see where Rudin proved the existence of the integral. You have to look at so called Bochner integration for this. Reference: Vector measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: Which edition of Rudin are you using? I am using 2nd Edition. He defines the integral as $y \in X$ such that $\lambda y = \int_Q \lambda f \, d\mu$ (which exists) for all $\lambda \in X^*$.

Comment: Go back to the tart of the section and look for standing assumptions. For example if $\mu$ is a Radon measure then $\mu(Q)<\infty$ by definition, since $Q$ is compact. (Rudin doesn't seem to like the term "Radon" but he often does restrict attention to Radon measures.) Or if the context implies that $\mu$ is actually a complex measure and here it just happens that $\mu\ge0$ then again it follows that $\mu(Q)<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I have tried, even in his Complex Analysis text, on the chapter, Positive Borel Measure, he doesn't mention the finiteness conditions.

Comment: Oh yes he does! In _Real and Complex Analysis_ he specifies $\mu(K)<\infty$ for compact $K$ in the statement of the Riesz Representation Theorem, then elsewhere he says things like "suppose $\mu$ is as in RRT"...

Comment: Sorry, which page is this? For what I know, on pg 47, he does not specify the finite conditions for his definition of Borel measure. For RRT, on pg41, he shows the existence of a measure $\mu$ which satisfies the finiteness condition - but this is not his definition.

Comment: I didn't say he includes the finiteness condition as part of the definition of Borel measure! Of course he doesn't -- it's _not_ part of the definition.

Comment: I was replying to your comment that he doesn't _mention_ the finiteness condition. He does so, in places where it's needed.

Comment: Was finally able to look it up. No, there's no reason I can see that $\int fd\mu$ should exist. One can show that it does exist if $\int||f||d\mu<\infty$. I conjecture that "Borel measure" was a typo for "Borel probability measure", since those are the only measures included in the theorem he gives on existence of vector-valued integrals.